# makemigrations for a model that is created via inspectdb

Tags: python, django

I have a database in microsoft sql server. I created tables and views in it.

I ran `py manage.py inspetdb view_Name > Models.py` and populated my models.py file with **managed=false**. I also dont want my model to alter my database. I just want it for data retrieval.

**Should I definitely run migrate/makemigrations?**

**After inspectdb should i apply makemigrations on my app or is just migrate enough?** And also what are the points to remember while using inspectdb on an existing database.

Also I have something like the below in my models.py file for all columns

```
created = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase
```

Is having the fieldname in lowercase safe ? Or should I change it as it is in my column? And what are those db_column='Created', blank=True, null=True fields. Not all my views have such fields. Only a few have such values.

Models.py contents

```
    # This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior.
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from django.db import models


class test1table(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Test1'
```

Migrations file 0001_intial.py

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.14 on 2019-11-28 07:22

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='test1table',
            fields=[               
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, db_column='Created', null=True
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'Test1',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Unmanaged models (managed=false) will not produce migrations so running makemigrations/migrate will not do anything with those tables and should be safe to run if you want to add other tables using Django

Comment: Lowercase variable names is the generally accepted as the standard and comes from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). `db_column='Created'` defines the name of the column in the table for that field, `blank=True` says that this field is not required when validating any forms generated for this model, `null=True` says that the database column for this field allows null values

Comment: I ran makemigrations and the migrate . I get error stating unable to create table as permission is not available. managed=false should not create table at all right?   I dnt want to add anything to my database

Comment: Yes, having `managed = False` in the model's Meta should exclude it from any migrations. What is in the migration file? Can you share the model that the migration is trying to create the table for?

Comment: I have updated the models.py file contents

Comment: Please attach the content of the generated migration file here, it could help understanding what you're doing wrong.

Comment: BTW, is this your first migration? As far as I understand, Django tries to create tables for its own use (users, groups, permissions, content types etc.) when running `./manage.py migrate` for the first time, and that might also fail if the database user doesn't have sufficient permissions

Comment: yes this is the first migration. Updated the migration file too in the question

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue, can you check that the user you are using to connect to the DB has full permissions for the schema?

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved my problem: I created a notepad file, pasted the code, changed the extension to .py and replaced the models.py file.
Success in migrate!